# PMD Maven Plugin ignores exclude properties Values for inner class

Tags: java, maven-plugin, pmd

I'm using PMD v3.12 in my current project.

I have a POJO with some properties:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String state;
   private String zip;
   private String town;
   private Integer id;
   private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
   private String locationOfBirth;

   // GETTERS & SETTERS, HASHCODE, TOSTRING

   .
   .
   .
}
```

I added an inner Builder class for this Pojo:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String state;
   private String zip;
   private String town;
   private Integer id;
   private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
   private String locationOfBirth;

   // GETTERS & SETTERS, HASHCODE, TOSTRING

   ...
   
   public static Builder builder() {
      return new Builder();
   }

   public static class Builder {
      private final Person person;
      
      public Builder() {
         this.person = new Person();
      }

      public Builder name(String name) {
         this.person.setName(name);
         return this;
      }

      // Other Methods to build an instance

      public Person build() {
         return this.person;
      }

   }

}
```

Now when PMD is executed, it tells me that the class `Person` violates `TooManyMethods` and should be refactored, pointing to the line number, where the inner class begins.
Since i don't want to refactor my Builder, i tried adding an exclusion to the `exclude-pmd.properties` file, but it doesn't work: 
`org.my.path.to.my.file.Person=TooManyMethods`
I also tried:
`org.my.path.to.my.file.Person.Builder=TooManyMethods`
`org.my.path.to.my.file.Builder=TooManyMethods`
and i tired adding `@SuppressWarnings("PMD")` on both, the parent class and the inner class, but nothing worked.
I am aware that lombok exists, but in my current company it's not allowed, also changing the settings of PMD to allow more Methods to a class is not possible.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the builder have to be an inner class of `Person`? It's a static inner class and doesn't seem to require any special visibility so why not create a `PersonBuilder` top-level class or a `Builder` in the same package? `Person.builder()` could still return an instance of that class.

Comment: Valid point, thanks! Never tought about it, i always implemented Builder as an inner class, but that should work as a work around.